# Telerik RadTree bound to XML DataSource

Tags: asp.net, xml, data-binding, telerik

I have a Telerik RadTree bound to an XMLDataSource.
I want to set a node's text to consist of 2 attributes (number and name).

See `<telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding>`

Example:

- "1. How are you?"
- "2. How old are you?"

XML:

```
<questions>
  <question name="How are you?" number="1" imageurl="">
  </question>
  <question name="How old are you?" number="2" imageurl="">
  </question>
</questions>
```

ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">              
  <DataBindings>  
    <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="questions" Text="Questions" 
       ImageUrl="/questions.png" Expanded="false" />   
    <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="question" 
       Text='[<%# DataBinder.Eval("number")%>].[<%# DataBinder.Eval("name")%>]' 
       ImageUrlField="imageurl" FormatString="{0}" Expanded="false" />
  </DataBindings>
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I use the NodeTemplate applied to all nodes to prepend "number." if found in xpath...

```
<telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">
    <NodeTemplate>
            <%# XPath("@number", "{0}.") %>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Text") %>
    </NodeTemplate>             
    <DataBindings>
        <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="questions" Text="Questions" ImageUrl="/questions.png" Expanded="false" />   
        <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="question" TextField="name" ImageUrlField="kpiimageurl" FormatString="{0}" Expanded="false" /> 
    </DataBindings>  
</telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Havn't tested this but give it a go:

XML:

```
<questions>
  <question name="How are you?" number="1" imageurl=""></question>
  <question name="How old are you?" number="2" imageurl=""></question>
</questions>
```

ASPX:

```
    <telerik:RadTreeView ID="RadTreeView1" runat="server">              
        <DataBindings>  
            <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="questions" Text="Questions" ImageUrl="/questions.png" Expanded="false" />   
            <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="question" Text='[<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "number")%>].[<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name")%>]' ImageUrlField="imageurl" FormatString="{0}" Expanded="false" />
       </DataBindings>
    </telerik:RadTreeView>
```

Comment: Thanks CKret, it seems close, but...
There is no DataItem property on Container.
I think if I can maybe specify something like:
DataBinder.Eval(Container.Attribute, "name")

Comment: perhaps DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.name")